# Issues with writing whitespaces when using std::ofstream

Tags: c++

During my efforts to get LittleFS filesystem to work on the ESP32 for another project,
I tried the demo project (https://github.com/joltwallet/esp_littlefs/blob/master/example/main/demo_esp_littlefs.c).

It uses the C way of writing to files and that works without any issues.

I've converted the write and read calls to use `std::ofstream` and `std::ifstream` respectively, since that matches the implementation of the main project I'm trying to get LittleFS to work here.

Please find my writing code below

```
// First create a file.
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Opening file");
std::ofstream of("/littlefs/hello.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
of.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);
std::noskipws(of);

of << std::noskipws;

of << std::string("LittleFS1234 Rocks!\n");
of.close();


ESP_LOGI(TAG, "File written");
```

The new code for reading the file

```
// Open renamed file for reading
ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Reading file");
std::fstream fo ("/littlefs/foo.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
fo.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);
std::noskipws(fo);

std::string read_data;

fo >> read_data;

fo.close();

ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Read from file: '%s' (len: %d)", read_data.c_str(), read_data.size());
```

The issue is, I'm writing *LittleFS1234 Rocks!\n*, but I'm only getting *LittleFS1234* back.

As you can see, I've tried to disable whitespace skipping and opening the file in binary on both the reading and the writing handles, but that doesn't seem to work. The length of the read file is 12 characters, which matches the *LittleFS1234*.

In between tests, I've erased the complete flash to ensure that the filesystem will be freshly formatted upon boot.

Please be aware, the example renames the output file from `hello.txt` to `foo.txt`

It looks to be the writing of the file that doens't work the way I expect it to, but I'm probably missing out on something.
Could it be an implementation detail in the ESP-IDF framework, that implements the std calls?

Comment: It's funny. I can reproduce your effect with a plain `std::istringstream`: [demo on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e3a9aa866a6398e) Though... 1st) It doesn't explain why your file has only 12 bytes. 2nd) I must admit that I cannot explain the effect. I never used `noskipws` in daily business...

Comment: `noskipws` only disables skipping of *leading* whitespace. It does not allow *embedded* whitespace in an input string. Instead use `getline` to read a whole text line.

Comment: I just figured out that the contents of the file are correctly written to the file, by using the C fgets function. However, that function only returns the string until the new line, so that took me a while to figure out.
However, I'd just like a way to read out the whole file at once, without dealing with new lines, spaces or anything else.

Comment: The doc. for [operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) does mention this behavior: _std::isspace(c, is.getloc()) is true for the next character c in is (this whitespace character remains in the input stream)._ I just wasn't aware that `noskipws` doesn't play a role in this...